# In Julia 1.0+: How do I get strings using redirect_stdout

Tags: julia

The [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.redirect_stdout) for `redirect_stdout`on version 1.1.0, that I am currently using, does not seem to give an example of how to use that function.  Maybe I missed it?

I want to capture the output of `println` and get it back as a string.

Here is an example:

```
julia> VERSION
v"1.1.0"

julia> (rd, wr) = redirect_stdout();

julia> println("This is a test.")

julia> # Get back the string "This is a test."

julia> # s = do_something_with_rd(rd)

julia> # s == "This is a test."

julia> # true
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

Based on the accepted answer below, here is a complete solution to my question:

```
julia> original_stdout = stdout;

julia> (rd, wr) = redirect_stdout();

julia> println("This is a test.")

julia> s = readline(rd)
"This is a test."

julia> s == "This is a test."
true

julia> redirect_stdout(original_stdout);

julia> println("Test of orig. stdout.")
Test of orig. stdout.
```

**Edit 2: A More Complete Example**

Here is an example of testing a variety of `print` and `println` function outputs using redirection of `stdout`.  Thanks to @Bogumił Kamiński for his answer and edit that made this more clear to me:

```
using Test

# Test redirect_stdout.
@testset "Example tests using redirect_stdout" begin
    original_stdout = stdout;
    (read_pipe, write_pipe) = redirect_stdout();
    print("Using print function.")
    println("Using println function.")
    println("Second use of println function.")
    println("Line 1.\nLine 2.\nLine 3.\nEND")
    println("""
    This is new line 1.
    This is new line 2. Next a Char = """)
    print('A')
    redirect_stdout(original_stdout);
    close(write_pipe)
    @test readline(read_pipe) == "Using print function.Using println function."
    @test readline(read_pipe) == "Second use of println function."
    @test read(read_pipe, String) == "Line 1.\nLine 2.\nLine 3.\nEND\n" * 
    "This is new line 1.\nThis is new line 2. Next a Char = \nA"
end

# Suppress unnecessary output when this file.
return nothing
```

Here is the output:

```
julia> include("test_redirect_stdout.jl")
Test Summary:                       | Pass  Total
Example tests using redirect_stdout |    3      3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just run `readline` on `rd` (or any other reading operation).

You have just to be careful that read operations on `rd` are blocking, i.e. the terminal will seem to hang when the operation cannot be completed. One solution is to use `@async` for this. For instance:

```
julia> (rd, wr) = redirect_stdout();

julia> @async global x = readline(rd) # if we did not put @async here the terminal would be blocked
Task (runnable) @0x0000000004e46e10

julia> x # x is yet undefined as readline is waiting for an input
ERROR: UndefVarError: x not defined

julia> println("something") # we feed data to stdout

julia> x # and readline has finished its work and bound the value to variable x
"something"
```

Of course if you know exactly that the data you want to read in is there just run `readline` or some other function and all will work without `@async`.

**EDIT**

Given the comments from [SalchiPapa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2374329/salchipapa) I think it is also add this pattern of possible usage as it is simplest to think of IMO:

```
original_stdout = stdout
(rd, wr) = redirect_stdout();

println("This is a test 1.")
println("This is a test 2.")
println("This is a test 3.")

redirect_stdout(original_stdout)

# you can still write to wr
println(wr, "This is a test 4.")

# you have to close it to make the read non-blocking
close(wr)

# the pipe is redirected to original stdout and wr is closed so this is non-blocking    
s = read(rd, String)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sprint` AKA "string print":

- https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/index.html#Base.sprint

```
julia> sprint(println, "This is a test")
"This is a test\n"
```

Comment: Agreed, but `sprint` and `redirect_stdout` are designed to handle a different use case. I use `redirect_stdout` when I run a third-party code that writes something to `stdout` and I want to capture it. In such cases you cannot use `sprint`. [Here](https://github.com/bkamins/Workshop-on-Optimization-Techniques/blob/d722aee731310ca51187b00a82246c08fc6ef0b0/10_jl_mc/01_stock_portofolio.jl#L39) is an example capturing the output of the external solver. And the question was about how to use `redirect_stdout` (but indeed your answer is a better solution for simple cases).

Comment: Maybe it could also be useful for him `Suppressor.@capture_out`  https://github.com/JuliaIO/Suppressor.jl/blob/b4ff08f0fe795a2ce9e592734a758c9e6d8e2bc4/src/Suppressor.jl#L124-L152  which uses IO stream redirects underneath.

Comment: Good point - actually I think it is worth to update my answer given your comment.

Comment: @SalchiPapa Good point about `Supprssor's @capture_out macro.  I had tried it and it worked great.  However, I was wanting a solution in Base Julia and the accepted answer provided that.  Anyway, it is good to have another tool in the box.

Comment: @Julia Learner also you could always copy paste `@capture_out` almost verbatim into your code base, as it uses only `Base`, but then you miss out updates and bug fixes.

Comment: @SalchiPapa Good point.  I actually did that copy paste you suggest, and then decided not to use it, and then decided well maybe  I would use it.  I found that `@capture_out` works really well.  Long term, not sure at this point whether I like `redirect_stdout` or `@caputure_out` better.  I think they both have good use cases, so will probably use both.  No question that `@caputure_out` is very succinct, though, which is nice.