# Is there a way to suppress outputs inside a function in a Julia Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

In a Jupyter cell, I'd like to call a function that has some `println`, `@show`, etc in it, but I don't want to see those outputs. Is there a way to call a function while suppressing outputs? I'm aware of `;`, but my understanding is that `;` only affects the return value.

For example, let's say you have a function

```
function testOutputs()
    @show("Show macro still showing")
    println("Println still showing")
    a = 1 + 2
end
```

Calling `testOutputs();` in a cell results in:

```
"Show macro still showing" = "Show macro still showing"
Println still showing
```

I would like it to print nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As phyatt's answer highlights it would often be better for library code to use a configurable logging mechanism. However, sometimes you want to call code that, for whatever reason, writes directly to stdout. One way to handle these cases is to use [`redirect_stdout`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.redirect_stdout).

For example:

```
real_stdout = stdout
(rd, wr) = redirect_stdout();
# Noisy code here
redirect_stdout(real_stdout)
```

You'd probably want to put this in a function or a macro or simply use [Suppressor.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Suppressor.jl) a library that provides these macros. If you want to capture the output the way the ipython `%%capture` magic does you can have a look at `@capture_out` in Suppressor.jl, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599148/in-julia-1-0-how-do-i-get-strings-using-redirect-stdout) and [this forum thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/jupyter-notebook-capture-stdout-and-stderr-like-python-capture-magic/26253/10).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Agreed with both answers that configurable logging is better, but this covers more cases.

Answer (score 1):

No one is stopping you from making those functions useless.  It warns you that you must import from `Base` to actually override them.

```
julia> import Base.println

julia> println(args...) = nothing
println (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> import Base.@show

julia> macro show(args...)
       return :(nothing) # TODO: make this a pass thru instead of a removal
       end
@show (macro with 1 method)

julia> testOutputs()
3

julia> testOutputs();
```

Occasionally a programmer will put an `@show` in the middle of an expressions, and this kind of macro override would make it break such lines.

The better alternatives IMHO are to use a logging library like `Memento.jl` or the baked in Logging of julia.  They have single line functions for mass disabling logging thru their mechanisms.

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Logging/
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Logging/#Logging.disable_logging

```
julia> @debug "Hello World"

julia> @info "Hello World"
[ Info: Hello World

julia> @warn "Hello World"
┌ Warning: Hello World
└ @ Main REPL[10]:1

julia> @error "Hello World"
┌ Error: Hello World
└ @ Main REPL[11]:1

julia> using Logging

julia> Logging.disable_logging(Logging.Error)
LogLevel(2001)

julia> @debug "Hello World"

julia> @info "Hello World"

julia> @warn "Hello World"

julia> @error "Hello World"
```

https://invenia.github.io/Memento.jl/latest/

```
Memento.config!("emergency")
```

Or without any additional libraries make a global flag at the top of your file called `debug_print` and swap it when needed.

```
julia> global debug_print = true
true

julia> function testOutputs()
           debug_print && @show("Show macro still showing")
           debug_print && println("Println still showing")
           a = 1 + 2
       end
testOutputs (generic function with 1 method)

julia> testOutputs();
"Show macro still showing" = "Show macro still showing"
Println still showing

julia> debug_print = false
false

julia> testOutputs();
```